# Code to expand columns in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export

When I export my data into excel, it loads up the columns but doesn't expand the columns. It shows the data without having to double click on the line to expand the columns. Can I write some code which will automatically auto-adjust the columns so that the cells can show the entire data? I'm using asp.net and c#.

The first picture is what it currently looks like & the second shows what I want it to look like.

[image: What it looks like]

[image: What I want it to look like]

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ISALog1ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec ProxyReport", conn);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(dataSet);

    GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1];
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
    GridView3.DataBind();

    dataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "1";
    dataSet.Tables[1].TableName = "2";
    dataSet.Tables[2].TableName = "3";

    int count = 3;

    ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();


    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[i.ToString()];
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Top" + i);
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
    }  

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelExport.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pack.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Excel.Range range;

range = ws.get_Range("A1", "1");
range.AutoFit();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofit)

Comment: @Cloud I am afraid I don't know what is epplus

Comment: @Cloud ye sit will work in epplus look at this link http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/218294 right at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thanks, in a rush right now but I'm sure it will work once i take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the BestFit property is what you want, though it might be buggy:

http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/discussions/248406/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution on the same problem.
The checked answer above didnt work for me directly.

It worked with a simple addition:

```
Excel.Range range;

range = ws.get_Range("A1", "1");
range.Columns. AutoFit();
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the concerned answer as most of it is from it.

Comment: You are definetely right @Fjodr.
But I have not enough reputation to comment on foreign answers. Sorry.